# Linux ACL behaviour: settings the mask changes 'ls' output, but not actual permissions

Tags: linux, access-control-list, chmod, posix

It might be the time of night, but this is puzzling me. Picture the following.

```
[root@node1 acltest]# getfacl foo/
# file: foo
# owner: root
# group: testuser
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::---

[root@node1 acltest]# ls -la .
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Feb  9 21:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root     4096 Feb  9 21:54 ..
drwxr-x---  2 root testuser 4096 Feb  9 21:53 foo
[root@node1 acltest]# setfacl -m m::rwx foo
[root@node1 acltest]# getfacl foo/
# file: foo
# owner: root
# group: testuser
user::rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::---

[root@node1 acltest]# ls -la .
total 24
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root     4096 Feb  9 21:53 .
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root     4096 Feb  9 21:54 ..
drwxrwx---+  2 root testuser 4096 Feb  9 21:53 foo
[root@node1 acltest]# su - testuser
[testuser@node1 ~]$ cd /acltest/foo/
[testuser@node1 foo]$ ls -la .
total 16
drwxrwx---+ 2 root testuser 4096 Feb  9 21:53 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Feb  9 21:53 ..
[testuser@node1 foo]$ touch bar
touch: cannot touch `bar': Permission denied
```

In words: I create a directory `foo`, with mode `0750`, `root` as owner and `testuser` as the group. (`testuser` is the private group of `testuser`, but that doesn't matter.)

The `getfacl` command correctly shows no ACL's on this directory and there is not mask yet. The mask will be set accordingly to the group permissions if I would add a named group or user now.

If I explicitly set the mask to `rwx` now, the group permissions as shown by `ls` change too. I know it happens the other way around (the mask changes when the group permissions change), but this seems puzzling.

The more puzzling because the `getfacl` output does *not* show the group permissions as `rwx` but - as said - `ls` does.

Which one is right? Apparently, the output of `getfacl` is right, because `testuser` cannot write to `foo`. As expected, by the way, because I did not grant the `testuser` group any permissions to do so.

It goes on. I cannot allow the `testuser` group write permissions on `foo` by just using `chmod`. I have to explicitly set an ACL using `setfacl -m g:testuser:rwx foo` to allow `testuser` to finally touch `foo/bar`.

Can someone explain the rationale behind the difference in the outputs of `getfacl` and `ls`? I know it can be tricky to have normal permissions go together with ACL's, but this seems plain wrong. (Though I expect to be missing something glaringly obvious ;))

I have already seen [Why does chmod(1) on the group affect the ACL mask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/352783/why-does-chmod1-on-the-group-affect-the-acl-mask)

Comment: I just verified that this behaviour happens on FreeBSD9, Debian, RHEL5 and RHEL6. So it's either a bug that has spread itself very broadly, or it's not a bug at all. In that case, someone explain this to me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the man(5) page of acl

> ```
>     ACL_MASK        The ACL_MASK entry denotes the maximum access
>                        rights that can be granted by entries of type
>                        ACL_USER, ACL_GROUP_OBJ, or ACL_GROUP.
> ```

and later:

> 3. else if the effective group ID or any of the supplementary group IDs
>            of the process match the file group or the qualifier of any entry of
>            type ACL_GROUP, then

```
          if the ACL contains an ACL_MASK entry, then

              if  the ACL_MASK entry and any of the matching ACL_GROUP_OBJ
              or ACL_GROUP  entries  contain  the  requested  permissions,
              access is granted,

              else access is denied.
```

This means that rwx *CAN* be granted on the dir, but the chmod bits have to agree with it.

Comment: Yeah, close. This states that the mask and the group have to agree on giving write access, which is logical. But it does not explain why 'ls' shows a file as writable by a group when it clearly is not.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Here again from the acl(5): `If the ACL has an ACL_MASK entry, the group permissions correspond to the permissions of the ACL_MASK entry.` I think that should answer the question.

Comment: Well, how about that. I completely missed that :) Thanks for taking the time to read that manpage more thoroughly than I did ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that when ACLs are used on an object, the permissions listed by ls -l is bit different.

Accoring to man ACL(5):

> CORRESPONDENCE BETWEEN ACL ENTRIES AND FILE PERMISSION BITS
>
> The permissions defined by ACLs are a superset of the permissions
>   specified by the file permission bits.
>
> There is a correspondence between the file owner, group, and other
>   permissions and specific ACL entries: the owner permissions correspond
>   to the permissions of the ACL_USER_OBJ entry. If the ACL has an
>   ACL_MASK entry, the group permissions correspond to the permissions of
>   the ACL_MASK entry.  Otherwise, if the ACL has no ACL_MASK entry, the
>   group permissions correspond to the permissions of the ACL_GROUP_OBJ
>   entry.  The other permissions correspond to the permissions of the
>   ACL_OTHER_OBJ entry.

So when using ACLs you should consider the group permission section of ls -l output as the ACL mask
.