# ACL settings not being inherited properly when creating sub directory

Tags: linux, access-control-list

I am trying to extend ACLs across sub directories that are being created under a parent but for some reason one of my groups is being switched to #effective r-x and the mask is being changed. Any ideas? is there some default umask?

```
Administrator@MyServer ~
$ setfacl -m d:u:Someuser:r-- somedir

Administrator@MyServer ~
$ getfacl somedir/
# file: somedir/
# owner: Administrator
# group: None
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:user1:r-x
group:user2:rwx          
mask:rwx
other:r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:user1:r-x
default:group:user2:rwx
default:mask:rwx
default:other:r-x

-mkdir /somedir/somedir

Administrator@MyServer ~
$ getfacl somedir/somedir
# file: somedir/somedir
# owner: Administrator
# group: None
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:user1:r-x
group:user2:rwx      #effective:r-x       
mask:r-x
other:r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:user1:r-x
default:group:user2:rwx
default:mask:rwx
default:other:r-x
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you absolutely sure that you have used `mkdir somedir/somedir` and not used the `-p`option like `mkdir -p somedir/somedir` ?

Because `mkdir -p` has a nasty bug on distribution <= 2014 (coreutils < 8.22), see [Conflicts between ACLs and umask](https://serverfault.com/questions/197263/conflicts-between-acls-and-umask/674166#674166)

The ACL entries applicable for subdirectories are `default:` and `mask`:

```
$ getfacl somedir/
default:group:user1:r-x
default:group:user2:rwx
default:mask:rwx
default:other:r-x
```

The **default:mask:rwx**, so the sub directory **should have been**:

```
group:user1:r-x
group:user2:rwx
mask:rwx
```

But mask is `mask:r-x`, so the permission lowered to r-x:

```
group:user2:rwx      #effective:r-x  
mask:r-x
```

For a better understanding of the relation between Unix group permission and ACL, read [Why does chmod(1) on the group affect the ACL mask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/352783/why-does-chmod1-on-the-group-affect-the-acl-mask)

### Conclusion

- Don't use `mkdir -p` when you use ACLs (unless you run Debian/Jesise, RHEL7...)
- Fix your problem with `chmod g+w somedir/somedir` or `setfacl -m mask:rwx somedir/somedir`